# Are Paths the most efficient way to draw changing shapes?

Tags: android, android-canvas

The app I'm building has to draw around 400 quadrilateral shapes onto the screen with a fluent frame rate. The shapes 255 permutations and are drawn rotated anywhere from 0-360 degrees. I don't think pre-rendering them would efficient, given the amount of memory it would take (I could be wrong though). They also have a 24-bit color range. Right now I'm drawing them with paths and all the rotation and translation is handled by the function generating the values. Although this implementation is working (all be it at a low frame rate of like 25), I just feel like there's a more efficient way of doing it. To be honest, openGL and java looks quite confusing, but if it's the only option then I would man up and learn it.

TL;DR
Is this code the most efficient for constantly changing shapes?

```
        void quad(Canvas canvas,Paint paint, float x1,float y1, float x2,float y2, float x3,float y3,float x4,float y4,  float xoff, float yoff, int color){
        float[] hsvc = { map(color,0,100,0,360),.8f,1};
        paint.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsvc));
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x1, y1);
        path.lineTo(x2, y2);
        path.lineTo(x3, y3);
        path.lineTo(x4, y4);
        path.close();
        path.offset(xoff, yoff);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your permutations ans how do you rotate the paths?

As `Path` seems to be mutable in Android, you might try to reuse an instance and see if it gives you better results (using `Path.reset()` for instance).

Comment: For now, I'm drawing triangles with variable length and color. Later on I will be drawing larger polygons. They are "rotated" by the code, that is to say, I send them the coordinates that take into account for rotation. I'll see how much of a performance gain reset() as opposed to making a new Path gives!

Comment: Also, rather than rotating your triangles by the code, you could try to use an affine transform (and keep reusing the same triangle without needing to reset it), but the speed gains would probably more apparent for complex shapes.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of followup:

Using Android's Canvas system, Paths were the most efficient way that I could find. I ended up using opengl which is a much better alternative.